# How to debug Grails and Plug-Ins sources IDEA

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, grails-plugin

How to debug Grails and Plug-Ins sources. I am using IntelliJ IDEA v10.5.1. I can debug in my application sources and partially in plug-ins. I can see all sources in IDE, but I can catch breakpoints there. How should I configure my environment?

Answer (score 1):

if you have the plugins' source installed you should be able to control click into the plugin sources and add breakpoints as usual.  Always try a `grails clean`.  If your breakpoints are being ignored, try adding a breakpoint farther up in the chain in stepping thru the code; you are probably not reaching the breakpoint but think you are.